# ng-model not working inside ng-controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-controller

I have created an angular directive of input

```
 mainApp.directive('myInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<label class="form-group"> <span>{{name}}</span>{{required}}
    <input class="form-control"  placeholder="{{placeholder}}" type="{{type}}" ng-required= "{{mandatory}}" > </label>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            placeholder: '@',
            type: '@',
            name: '@',
            mandatory: '@',
            value:'@',
        },
    }
});
```

the controller

```
        mainApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
             $scope.Firstname = ' ';
}]);
```

the HTML

```
<my-Input type="text" placeholder="First name Last name" mandatory="0" ng-model="$ctrl.Firstname"></my-Input>
    <h4>{{$ctrl.Firstname}}</h4>
```

Unable to print the input text inside  tag. Please help.
Demo URL: http://codepen.io/JEETPAL/pen/pRWmKJ?editors=1010

Comment: You are closing your input with `</arc-input>`

Comment: should be <my-input> (lowercase i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `ng-model="Firstname"` instead of `ng-model="$ctrl.Firstname"` in your controller. If you didnt indicate `controller as $ctrl`

And also

You should add `ng-model` inside of your directive's template and send your ng-model value through binding `ngmodel-value = "Firstname"` and then in your directive's scope add `ngmodelValue = "="` for two way binding

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZwzOm?editors=1010

Comment: as per your suggestion $ctrl is removed but still it not working.

Comment: you should add ng-model inside of your directive's template and send your ng-model value through binding ngmodel-value = "Firstname" and then in your directive's scope add ngmodelValue = "=" for two way binding

Comment: if I use simple input with ng-model it working, but it not working with my directive

Comment: Thanks @salih şenol çakarcı,